# VS Code JavaScript remove semicolon. Убрать точку с запятой JavaScript VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Всех приветствую, у меня такая проблема, использую VS Code, пишу там на чистом JS (просто учусь), ввожу к примеру сокращение log и нажимаю Tab и мне выдает, console.log()**;**, но мне нужно, чтобы было без точки с запятой. Пробовал prettier, но каждый раз его проживать - не круто.. К тому же prettier бывает удаляет нужные мне скобки.

P.S Гугл есть гуглил сто раз, не нашел ничего на счет этого

Comment: А чем вам точка с запятой мешает?

Comment: Эстетически, я привык писать без везде, а там такая заподлянка.. То есть допустим уже много строк кода написано, а там бац, и точка с запятой и все время их чистить - контрпродуктивно)

Comment: Эстетически лучше с точкой с запятой, добавте их во всех строках вместо того, чтобы чистить.

Comment: Я выразил свое мнение, а вы мне начали навязать свое.. Без претензий, спасибо за старания)

Comment: @мишаня чтобы не быть голословным и не скидывать все на личное мнение [точка с запятой](https://learn.javascript.ru/coding-style#tochka-s-zapyatoy). Для професионального уровня оперировать понятиями "мнения" не приемлимо. Опрерируйте понятием "стандарт", например [этим](https://standardjs.com/)

Comment: Если в языке есть возможность их не ставить, то это сделано не просто так. Я знаю разработчиков, которые их не ставят, да и мне приятней так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Найти нужный язык для добавления сниппета, кликнуть и откроется его json файл. Заменить содержимое на:

```
{
    "Console log": {
        "prefix": "log",
        "body": "console.log($1)",
        "description": "Log output to console"
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, возьму на заметку если надо будет что-то еще подправить